# Wildfly - @TransactionAttribute -

Tags: java, hibernate, jboss, transactions, wildfly

In my project with Wildfly 10, java 8, mysql, camel and hibernate

the methodKO persists the entity orderEntity("ko"), call methodOK and goes in exception; methodOK persists the entity orderEntity("ok")

Despite exception in methodKO, I want found orderEntity("ok") in db, so I annotated the methodOK with @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
but this doesn't works

Here the details on configuration files:

standalone-full-ha.xml:

```
<datasources>
<xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true" use-ccm="true">
....
</datasources>
```

persistence.xml:

```
<persistence-unit name="camel" transaction-type="JTA">
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/myDS</jta-data-source>
....
```

MyBean:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    OrderDAO orderDAO;

    private void methodKO() throws Exception {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ko"));
        methodOK();
        throw new Exception("err");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    private void methodOK() {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ok"));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to EJB 3.1:

> A transaction attribute is a value associated with each of the
> following methods:
>
> a) a method of a bean’s business interface
>
> b) a method exposed through the
> bean class no-interface view

This means that any Transactional annotations on private methods are useless.

I would define both of those methods as **public**:

```
@Stateless

public class MyBean {
    @Inject
    OrderDAO orderDAO;

    public void methodKO() throws Exception {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ko"));
        methodOK();
        throw new Exception("err");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void methodOK() {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ok"));
    }

}
```

It would be a good practice that this bean would implement an interface actually containing those two methods on top of everything.

Comment: This will not work either. The call to `methodOK` is made as a regular method call and it's annotations are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, throwing a checked exception will not normally trigger a transaction rollback unless you specifically configure for this using [@ javax.ejb.ApplicationException(rollback = true)](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ejb/ApplicationException.html) on a specific Exception type. Unchecked exceptions trigger rollback by default.

For the reasons described nicely by Maciej you need to change the way that you try to implement this logic. There are a couple of ways to achieve the behaviour that you want:

The ugly way:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    @Resource
    private SessionContext sessionContext;

    @Inject
    OrderDAO orderDAO;

    public void methodKO() throws Exception {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ko"));
        sessionContext.getBusinessObject(MyBean.class).methodOK();
        throw new RuntimeException("err");
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void methodOK() {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ok"));
    }

}
```

The tidy way:

```
@Stateless
public class MyBean {

    @Inject
    OrderDAO orderDAO;

    public void methodKO() throws Exception {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ko"));
    }

    @TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRES_NEW)
    public void methodOK() {
        orderDAO.create(new orderEntity("ok"));
    }

}


@Stateless
public class MyBusinessBean {

    @Inject
    private MyBean myBean;

    public void businessMethod() {
        myBean.methodKO();
        myBean.methodOK();
        throw new RuntimeException("Trip rollback");
    }
}
```